# Odd SDL VSYNC behaviour when monitor is set to 50 Hz

Tags: c++, sdl2, frame-rate, vsync

I am observing strange behaviour with VSync in SDL. I have this code:

```
int main()
{
   SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
   SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER, "opengl");

   auto window = SDL_CreateWindow("window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1200, 480, 0);
   auto renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

   while (true)
   {
      static auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      auto elapsed_us = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count();
      start = end;

      std::cout << elapsed_us << std::endl;

      SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
   }
}
```

So when I set my monitor to `60 Hz` I get output as expected:

```
16673
17489
16011
16653
...
```

Meaning each cycle's duration is around 16.667 ms. Same when I set my monitor to `75 Hz` it showscorrect values around 13.333 ms.

But when I set it to `50 Hz` the output will be like this:

```
16845
3131
16702
3424
16772
3158
16825
3147
16872
3129
...
```

It seems like the VSync signal comes twice per 20 ms period. Once at around 16.667 ms mark and the second time at 20 ms.

How can this be explained?

Comment: Okay, so you actually get 50 hz. Did you try to see the behavior on another monitor?

Comment: No, I didn't. Yes in sum it's 50Hz but why in two steps? Could this be a monitor thing? Is there a program I can visualize VSync signals?

Comment: Okay it may be MacOS having a problem with OpenGL. When I omit the `SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER, "opengl")` line it works as expected.

Comment: Isn't OpenGL deprecated on macOS?